# Nexus 5X changes time after phone calls

Tags: clock, nexus-5x

Almost every time I make a phone call, the time on my phone changes. Typically it goes forward about 7 hours, but sometimes it's a little different. To fix it, I open up settings and turn the automatic time off and then on again. I did try leaving the automatic time off, but the error persists.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is this EVERY phone call, or just those made from a specific location? i.e. Is automatic time set from the most accessible cell tower consistently? You say ALMOST, as in you sometimes connect via a different cell tower and the problem doesn't recur? What is the timezone you are in? Could it be related to a UTC diff problem?

Comment: [Maybe related?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/205315/131553)

Comment: I haven't noticed a pattern of which phone calls make it change. I don't know if it is related to the location or not, but I know it doesn't matter who the call is with, as it has happened with multiple people. It still happens even if automatic time and time zone is turned off. I am in Mountain Standard Time. I am using Google Fi, so maybe it is related to whether or not the call is over the internet or a cell tower. I'll keep track of it and see if a notice a pattern.

Comment: Mountain Time is UTC-7h, which correlates to your stated problem (but this could be confirmation bias). Maybe a cell tower is using UTC time? This would be further substantiated if you find some pattern to the problem calls being from a narrow geographical location. It is unlikely a lot of cell towers would be configured to widen the geography.

Comment: Ok, I have narrowed down some details. The time change only happens when I make or receive calls in my apartment. If I go a block or so in either direction from my apartment, it works just fine. The bubble may be smaller, but I haven't tested it explicitly. Also, if I turn off wifi and location, it still happens. So it's not related to whether or not the call is using VoIP. Also, it is always exactly 7 hours.