# Pixel keeps changing time (losing 1 hour at random)

Tags: clock, date-and-time

I have a Pixel 4 phone running Android 11. For the past 3 days, I've started having a strange problem where the time on my phone changes to be 1 hour earlier. I'm physically located in Denver, CO, USA, which is solidly in the mountain time zone (eg not by a zone boundary).

Just this morning, the following happened:

- 7:00 AM - phone time is correct, phone alarm goes off (scheduled).
- 8:00 AM - phone alarm goes off again -- phone shows 7:00 AM as the time.
- 8:04 AM - phone corrects itself, time goes back to the correct time.

Yesterday something similar happened:

- 7:00 AM - phone alarm goes off ... phone thinks that it's 6:00 AM
- 7:30 AM - phone still thinks it's 6:30 AM
- 7:32 AM - phone corrects itself, time goes back to the correct time; notifies me about the missed 7AM alarm.

In grid form:

| Day | Actual Time | Phone Time | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Today | 7:00 AM | 7:00 AM | Scheduled alarm (7AM) |
| Today | 8:00 AM | 7:00 AM | Scheduled alarm (7AM) |
| Today | 8:04 AM | 8:04 AM | Spontaneous correction |
| Yesterday | 7:00 AM | 6:00 AM | Scheduled alarm (6AM) |
| Yesterday | 7:30 AM | 6:30 AM | Checked phone, incorrect time still shown |
| Yesterday | 7:32 AM | 7:32 AM | Spontaneous correction; alerted to missed alarm |

I don't know if it happens at other times of day, or only between 6:00-8:00 AM; that just happens to be when I actively look at my phone or (sync'd) smart-watch, or have alarms that go off at those times.

During today's hiccup (at 8:00 AM when it thought it was 7:00 AM), I checked the settings and it shows that it flipped from the correct daylight savings time zone to the incorrect one -- it it was using Mountain Standard Time instead of Mountain Daylight Time. I have it set to use the network-provided time and time-zone.

This is a screenshot of the 'date & time' settings that I took at 8:02 AM Mountain Daylight Time (7:02 AM Mountain Standard Time according to my phone):
[image: screenshot of settings|thumb]

How do I get this to stop happening? I'd like to avoid turning off the time sync because the other devices I do this on suffer from clock drift and it's a hassle to deal with.

Comment: As Android can make use of multiple time sources like the cellular network and an NTP service it is not clear where the problems come from. The time sync documentation of Android may contain some interesting commands you could try to find out more: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/time-source

Comment: I'm not actually using mobile data. The phone has been on wifi only the whole time (Google Fiber). I'll review the document though, thanks.

Comment: Possibly related issue since Android 9: [Time zone keeps changing wildly](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/205315/44325)

Comment: I looked at that question, but the two bug tracker issues are closed as either obsolete or infeasible, and it was against an older Android version.

Comment: The time sync in cellular network is as far as I know independent of mobile data. The cell tower send the time as part of the GSM protocol.

Comment: Capitalizing on the comment of @Robert, can you localize the problem to a particular location in your house/building? Can two cell towers be competing for connection at that location, and, if found to be consistently localized, can mean one of the towers is incorrectly set for DST?

Comment: It could be a localization issue with a cell tower; the tall buildings play havoc on my connectivity and it could be bouncing me between towers even though I'm not physically moving. My phone just swapped back to standard time again, and I haven't moved between when I posted the question and now. Rebooting the phone forced it back onto daylight time, but I'm not sure how long that'll "stick".

Comment: ... and less than 30 minutes later we're back on the wrong time zone. >_<